# Create dummy column with certain type in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have the following statement:

```
 CREATE TABLE `test` SELECT * FROM (SELECT
                'Placeholder' AS 'dynamic_1'
            FROM
                answer) AS test
```

The resulting table `test` has a column `dynamic_1` that is varchar(11)

First question is - why does it set a fix length of the column to 11?

Second question is - in this scenario I would like the resulting column `dynamic_1` to be of type TEXT instead of varchar(), how do I accomplish this?

Comment: `"why does it set a fix length of the column to 11?"` - Probably because `'Placeholder'` is 11 characters wide.  It needs 11 characters to store that, and doesn't need any more.  `"I would like the resulting column dynamic_1 to be of type TEXT instead of varchar()"` - Can you just define the column in a normal `CREATE TABLE` statement then?  That way you can define the column however you like.

Comment: Ahh good catch @David.

Comment: @David No not in this case. This is a very simplified version of a much larger query. It needs to be in this format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only know this because I read the manual. I know... cheating, right?

```
SELECT * FROM my_table;
+--------+--------+------------+------------+
| emp_no | salary | from_date  | to_date    |
+--------+--------+------------+------------+
|  10001 |  60117 | 1986-06-26 | 1987-06-26 |
|  10001 |  62102 | 1987-06-26 | 1988-06-25 |
|  10001 |  66074 | 1988-06-25 | 1989-06-25 |
|  10001 |  84917 | 1999-06-23 | 2000-06-22 |
|  10001 |  85112 | 2000-06-22 | 2001-06-22 |
|  10001 |  85097 | 2001-06-22 | 2002-06-22 |
|  10001 |  88958 | 2002-06-22 | 9999-01-01 |
|  10002 |  65828 | 1996-08-03 | 1997-08-03 |
|  10002 |  65909 | 1997-08-03 | 1998-08-03 |
|  10002 |  67534 | 1998-08-03 | 1999-08-03 |
|  10002 |  69366 | 1999-08-03 | 2000-08-02 |
|  10002 |  71963 | 2000-08-02 | 2001-08-02 |
|  10002 |  72527 | 2001-08-02 | 9999-01-01 |
+--------+--------+------------+------------+

CREATE TABLE my_new_table(emp_no TEXT NOT NULL) SELECT emp_no FROM my_table;

SELECT * FROM my_new_table;
+--------+
| emp_no |
+--------+
| 10001  |
| 10001  |
| 10001  |
| 10001  |
| 10001  |
| 10001  |
| 10001  |
| 10002  |
| 10002  |
| 10002  |
| 10002  |
| 10002  |
| 10002  |
+--------+

DESCRIBE my_new_table;
+--------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| emp_no | text | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: This does indeed work!                                                                     CREATE TABLE `test`(dynamic_1 TEXT NOT NULL) SELECT * FROM (SELECT
                'Placeholder' AS dynamic_1 
            FROM
                sq_form_answer) AS test

Answer (score 0):

> First question is - why does it set a fix length of the column to 11?

Since 'Placeholder' uses 11 character hence it makes it as varchar(11)

> Second question is - in this scenario I would like the resulting column dynamic_1 to be of type TEXT instead of varchar(), how do I accomplish this?

You can try to use the CAST operator to achieve it. Or better(*as David pointed out*) you can create a table with the valid datatype what you need.

Comment: The result of the cast can not be a TEXT type. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast

Comment: To be more precise, the *constant string* `'Placeholder'` is a `VARCHAR(11)`, which then makes the inner `select` have a `VARCHAR(11)` column, which is then selected by the outer `select`, which then drives the `create table` :-)